# Confusion about importing python module residing in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory that contains my python files:

```
bin/
   main.py
   module1.py # there are no classes in this module. Only functions.
```

I'm trying to import module1 into main.py but it doesn't work.

What is surprising is that the following code gets accepted in main.py:

```
from module1
```

But I don't have a class in module1 that I can import. And if I try to import it directly then it leads to an error:

```
import module1
```

Why does Python throw an error for the import statement but not for the "from module1" statement?

Also, how can I import a python module when both files reside in the same directory, without modifying the windows path?

Comment: What error does Python throw for the import statement? What is in module1?

Comment: well just do `from module1 import *` to import all the functions. But this is a bad idea as everything will be scattered all ove

Comment: What is your working directory?  If it is not bin/ then you will likely have to append ./bin/ to sys.path or set bin/ up as a python package using an __init__.py file.

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` under the bin to register bin as a package? then you can do `from bin import Module1`

Comment: @EugeneProut There is just a print statement. _print(__name__)_ . The error thrown is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...`.

Comment: @Onyambu I had already tried that. With import * python throws the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module1'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: @JohnS I'm on windows. The current directory is not in the windows path. If I add it to the windows path then the import statement works. However, I'm trying to import the module without adding it to the path. There is no __init__.py in the folder yet. I'm trying to understand whether it is possible or not to import the module directly.

Comment: You should not have to update the windows path, just the python path.  This can be done in your code by appending bin/ to the  sys.path dictionary where python looks for external references.  Perhaps something like `sys.path.append("./bin/")` before trying to `import module1`